Chained restriction?
I'm not sure the title describes what I‌ mean.
We have three classes: Candidate, CandidatesList and Election, connected by two object properties: onList and runsIn, where:
Domain onList some Individual
Range onList some CandidatesList
Domain runsIn some CandidatesList
Range runsIn some Election
What's an expression to affect that:
a Candidate can run on one CandidatesLIst per Election.
In other words:
a Candidate can be on many CandidatesLists as long as no more than one of them is running in a given Election.
The reasoning I‌ come up with clearly has a syntactical error, and I'm not sure it is even logically correct. In Protege's Candidate's EquivalentTo:
onList exactly 1 CandidatesList and ( onList some CandidateList and (CandidatesList runsIn some Election))


you don't have variables in OWL, something like what you wrote in the end is (CandidatesList runsIn some Election) just invalid syntax. You could write the last part as onList some (CandidateList and runsIn some Election) - not that I know exactly if this is what you want to express - it just describes "all individuals being on some candidate list that runs in an election"

Yes, I know. I didn't mean that as a variable, despite of how that may have implied.
